# Cant get JSONArray data with having zero's in Ajax

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, struts2, json

Here I am using the Struts2 framework. I am trying to get `JSONArray` data like

```
jSONArray.add("[[4.4,7.0,3.3,6.2,1.3,1.7,],[4.9,6.7,1.1,3.3,4.4,6.1,],
                [5.4,6.9,4.8,5.2,4.9,6.8,],[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,],
                [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,],[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,],]");
```

this is 6 X 6 array data,and i am trying to print this data using Ajax,but i am getting output like this
4.4,7,3.3,6.2,1.3,1.7,4.9,6.7,1.1,3.3,4.4,6.1,5.4,6.9,4.8,5.2,4.9,6.8,,,
I need output as 
4.4,7,3.3,6.2,1.3,1.7,4.9,6.7,1.1,3.3,4.4,6.1,5.4,6.9,4.8,5.2,4.9,6.8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 . 
I didn't get the zero values.If i use 6 X 5 array data then it perfectly working.

Action:

```
public class JsonAction extends ActionSupport{
public String jasonRequest(){

        jSONObject=new JSONObject();
        jSONArray=new JSONArray();        
        jSONArray.add("[[4.4,7.0,3.3,6.2,1.3,1.7,],[4.9,6.7,1.1,3.3,4.4,6.1,],
                        [5.4,6.9,4.8,5.2,4.9,6.8,],[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,],
                        [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,],[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,],]");

        jSONObject.put("status", jSONArray);
        System.out.println("json result "+jSONObject.get("status").toString());
        return SUCCESS;
    }
 }
```

Page:

```html
<Html>
<head>
 <script>
     function abc(){
          var vals1='hai';
                $.ajax({   
                     url: "JsonAction.action",
                     method: "POST", 
                     data: 't1='+vals1,
                     dataType: "json",                                  
                     success:function(result){
       document.getElementById("name0").innerHTML=result.status[0];
      }
   })
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
       <input type="submit" name="b1" value="add" onclick="abc()"/>
       <div id="name0"> </div> 
</body>
</Html>
```

Comment: Debug your app. Is your json ok, do you receive it in js, etc.

Comment: i debug my app,but it still showing the same.

Comment: These are the Jar files i added for json.     json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
json-rpc-1.0.jar
jsonplugin-0.32.jar
jsonrpc-1.0.jar

Comment: @user3363670 You can send a stream result if you like to use these libraries.

Comment: i need to send as JSONArray.

Comment: why its happening when passing zeros?